# What data structures in .NET do O(1) on Contains() calls?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm drawing a blank here; I can't find it, unless I'm really overlooking something under my nose.

I'm trying to store a list of `int`s in a data structure.
But after I add them, I will later in code check if an `int` exists in the list already.

The generic `List<int>` does an O(n) operation with its `Contains()`.
I want something that works as fast as `Dictionary<>`'s `Contains()`, which does an O(1) operation because it hashes the keys.

I know the answer is something so simple and that I've worked for too long today I can't remember it.

Help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Will [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) work for you?

Comment: cannot be used if you really need to store a list, though (the order will be lost).

Comment: Wow that simple...... and it was RIGHT in front of me the whole time. I wish I can answer this question faster =).  Thanks!

Comment: Oh I don't care about the order, Thilo.  That's exactly what I want; just a bag of integers that I can index quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Since I work with C# 2.0 because of platform constraints, I usually use `Dictionary<int,bool>`, with the constraint that if a key is in the map, the bool is true (so the bool isn't really encoding any information -- it's just a substitute for the missing unit type from .NET).